# Command line executable that gets the ActionScript version of a SWF

Tags: windows, open-source, command-line, flash

I am looking for an .exe that can be called from the command line to return the ActionScript version from just the SWF file.

The program would need to be free/open license, as this is would be used in a commercial application.

The program also needs to be able to run without internet.

It would be preferable for the program to return the version as a single line, but not necessary.

Edit: The application that is going to use this information needs to determine the actionscript version BEFORE the SWF is loaded, so using another SWF such as [this](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/utils/SWFReader.as) is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042552/analyse-swf-files-with-java